# How to create a image gallery based on image URL instead ID in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, image, url, gallery, shortcode

How to create a image gallery on WordPress using their URLs instead IDs? The default gallery shortcode is [gallery ids="729,732,731,720"]. I need to create gallery based on image URL, like:

```
[gallery urls="
http://example.com/images/image01.jpg,
http://example.com/images/image02.jpg,
http://example.com/images/image03.jpg
"]
```

Obs.: All images is hosted on same domain of WordPress site.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can do it with original shortcode but you can create your own gallert shortcode where you can take the urls are shortcode arg and then from those urls you can get the attachment ids using [attachment_url_to_postid](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/attachment_url_to_postid/) then you can call the original shortcode by passing those attachment ids that you got from urls.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that...